# What is the opposite of now.date.addDays?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am writing a little script whereby an action is fired if something has happened in the last few days.

So I have a database of posts and their dates, I want to select all of those records that are within say the last 2 days.

To select all that are within the last 2 days I need to know what the date was 2 days ago, so what is the opposite of now.date.addDays()?

It doesn't seem to exist! there is no removeDays()

Comment: that simple...? i just did a face-palm :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Subtraction is mathematically equivalent to adding the [additive inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_inverse):

```
Now.Date.AddDays(-2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Negative integers, there is no `SubtractDays()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Now.Date.AddDays(-2)
```

Try use the above

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there is no explicit method for subtracting days, but you can pass in a negative value to the addDays method to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

can use this

```
// reference : https://date-fns.org/v2.30.0/docs/subDays

// Subtract 10 days from 1 September 2014:
const result = subDays(new Date(2014, 8, 1), 10)
//=> Fri Aug 22 2014 00:00:00
```

Comment: A little late to the partay there..